# Packaging with pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pyinstaller

Good afternoon good people

On my **Ubuntu 20.04** I created a .py file and tried to package using **pyinstaller**.

```
a = "It worked"
print (a)
```

He created it but when I went to the distance and ran the operating system he returned the following message:

**There is no application installed for" shared library "files. Do you want to search for an application to open this file?**

I believe that my operating system must be missing some lib.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running it in terminal

```
chmod +x filename
./filename
```

or if it's an executable:

```
/path/to/file
```

Comment: I created a file for Linux and running with ./file it works, but if you click 2x it doesn't work nor does it have an error.